# webpack.config.js unable to recognize ES6 grammar

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

webpack.config.js unable to recognize ES6 grammar

code as below:

```
devServer: {
    ...webpackDevServerProxy(proxyConfig),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000
}

throw error:
 ...webpackDevServerProxy(proxyConfig),
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use something like babel to transpile your config files

https://babeljs.io/